# Future not returning String

Tags: flutter, dart, future

Why do I keep getting 'Instance of...' when I'm trying to get a String. What's wrong with the function?

```
Future<string?> counter() async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      context.watch<FoodCount>().display(widget.food).toString();
      return widget.food.quantity.toString();
    });
    int count = widget.food.quantity;
    // print(count);
    return count;
  }
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class FoodQuantity extends StatefulWidget {
  final Food food;
  FoodQuantity(this.food);

  @override
  State<FoodQuantity> createState() => _FoodQuantityState();
}

class _FoodQuantityState extends State<FoodQuantity> {
  final int amount = 0;

  String getCurrency() {
    var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(name: 'NGN');
    return format.currencySymbol;
  }

  Future<int> counter() async {
    final int result = await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      int result = context.read<FoodCount>().display(widget.food);
      return result;
    });
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      height: 40,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(-1, 0), //0.3
            child: Container(
              width: 120,
              height: double.maxFinite,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(width: 15), //Spacing
                  Text(
                    getCurrency(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    widget.food.price.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(1, 0), //0.3
            child: Container(
              height: double.maxFinite,
              width: 120,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff453658),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (context.read<Counter>().count != 0) {
                        context.read<Counter>().decrement();
                        // widget.food.quantity--;
                        userOrders.remove(widget.food);
                        context.read<FoodCount>().decrement(widget.food);
                        setState(() {});
                      } else {
                        context.read()<Counter>();
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      '-',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      counter().toString(),
                      // context
                      //     .watch<FoodCount>()
                      //     .display(widget.food)
                      //     .toString(),
                      // widget.food.quantity.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      context.read<Counter>().increment();
                      context.read<FoodCount>().increment(widget.food);
                      // widget.food.quantity++;
                      userOrders.add(widget.food);
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      '+',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I made a provider class `FoodCount` that monitors the value `quantity` of object type `Food`. The async function is supposed to simply return the `quantity` of the `Food` provided to it

Provider:

```
class FoodCount with ChangeNotifier {

  int increment(Food food) {
    food.quantity++;
    int foodCount = food.quantity;
    notifyListeners();
    return foodCount;
  }

  int decrement(Food food) {
    food.quantity--;
    int foodCount = food.quantity;
    notifyListeners();
    return foodCount;
  }

  int display(Food food) {
    int count = food.quantity;
    notifyListeners();
    return count;
  }

  void update() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Food:

```
class Food {
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  int price;
  int quantity;
  bool favourited;
  List<Map<String, String>> ingredients;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
  Food(this.imgUrl, this.desc, this.name, this.waitTime, this.score, this.price,
      this.quantity, this.ingredients, this.about, this.favourited,
      {this.highlight = false});
}
```

Comment: Can you add your full log and explain what you are expecting

Comment: This won't even compile. `string?` isn't a type (presumably you meant `String?`), and you can't return an `int` from an `async` function that is declared to return a `Future<String?>`.  If you're seeing "Instance of Future...", then that means that the *caller* is not `await`ing the returned `Future` to extract the `String` value.

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh I just updated the post

Answer (score 1):

First off, here's a tip: you're using `Future.delayed` as a way to get a value after a delay. Try splitting that up into two parts. Instead of

```dart
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
  context.watch<FoodCount>().display(widget.food).toString();
  return widget.food.quantity.toString();
});
int count = widget.food.quantity;
```

Try

```dart
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
context.watch<FoodCount>().display(widget.food.toString());
return widget.food.quantity.toString();
```

Secondly, the other users are right: when you receive a `Future<String>`, you can't actually get to the `String` without `await`ing it. Problem is, you can use `await` in an `async` function, and `build` is not `async`. Conceptually, think of it as "you need to wait 5 seconds for the delay, but your user needs a UI *now*".

You can solve this using [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), which allows you to return some widget until the future finishes.

```dart
// In your State class:
late final Future<int> futureCounter;  // the future containing your data

@override
void initState() {
  // Start your counter now, before the UI loads
  futureCounter = counter();
  super.initState();
}

// in your build:
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: futureCounter,
    builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
      snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : "Loading...",
    )
    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Future.delayed is by itself a `Future`, so you cannot track it without an `await` to keep the result.
Take a look here, how you can make it, then take care of the difference about a sequential method and a Future method;

```
Future<String?> counter() async {
    // Future.delayed is by itself a future, so you connot track it without an await to get the result
    final String result = await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
       var a = "I'm a Future after 5 seconds" ;
       return a;
    });
    
    return result; 
    // Here is not the result you want because this method might be not a Future I think
    // int count = widget.food.quantity;
    // print(count);
    // return count;
  }
```

Or

```
  Future<String?> counter2() async {
    return  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      var a = "I'm a Future after 5 seconds" ;
      return a;
    });

    
    // Here is not the result you want because this method might be not a Future I think
    // int count = widget.food.quantity;
    // print(count);
    // return count;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Future and you want to get value from it, you should use **await** or **then()**
try to use this code:

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      context.watch<FoodCount>().display(widget.food).toString();
      return widget.food.quantity.toString();
    });
```